# Split column into separate columns based on separator strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**For example we have a csv file with**

`name            age    address
john             25     koramangala banglore #@ sales maneger %$ india 
harshuth rao     36     belandur banglore #@  maneger %$ india 
vijay kumar      45     ulsoor banglore #@ sales maneger %$ india 
suhas            25     koramangala banglore #@analist %$ india 
mithun           22     venkatapura banglore #@ execitive %$ india`

**how to make this and add to different column**

```
name           age  city                  country     position 
john           25   koramangala banglore  india       sales maneger
harshuth rao   36   belandur banglore     india       maneger
vijay kumar    45   ulsoor banglore       india       sales maneger
suhas          25   koramangala banglore  india       analist
mithun         22   venkatapura banglore  india       execitive
```

**The code i am using is**

```
 import re
 import csv
 with open("/home/vipul/Desktop/example.csv", 'rb') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in mycsv:
        text = row[0]
        txt = re.findall(r'(\w+[\s\w]*)\b', text)  
        print txt
```

**This is how it looks in txt editor**

```
name ,age ,address
john,25,koramangala banglore +ACMAQA- sales maneger +ACUAJA- india
harshuth rao ,36,belandur banglore +ACMAQA-  maneger +ACUAJA- india 
vijay kumar,45,ulsoor banglore +ACMAQA- sales maneger +ACUAJA- india
suhas,25,koramangala banglore +ACMAQA-analist +ACUAJA- india
mithun,22,venkatapura banglore +ACMAQA- execitive +ACUAJA- india
```

Comment: read the space separated csv as a pandas dataframe and split the city column on the special character

Comment: i am new to coding i dont know much can you help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing regular expression in the `sep` of `read_csv`

```
import io
t = """name ,age , address
john,25,koramangala banglore +ACMAQA- sales maneger +ACUAJA- india
harshuth rao ,36,belandur banglore +ACMAQA-  maneger +ACUAJA- india 
vijay kumar,45,ulsoor banglore +ACMAQA- sales maneger +ACUAJA- india
suhas,25,koramangala banglore +ACMAQA-analist +ACUAJA- india
mithun,22,venkatapura banglore +ACMAQA- execitive +ACUAJA- india"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), 
                 sep='\s*\+ACMAQA-\s*|\s*\+ACUAJA-\s*|\s*,\s*', engine='python')
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ["name", "age", "city", "position", "country"]


    name          age                   city    position      country
0   john           25   koramangala banglore    sales maneger   india
1   harshuth rao   36   belandur banglore       maneger         india
2   vijay kumar    45   ulsoor banglore sales   maneger         india
3   suhas          25   koramangala banglore    analist         india
4   mithun         22   venkatapura banglore    execitive       india
```

Comment: Gosh damn, I wouldn't want to be an analist... also see your column headers

Answer (score 2):

First, load your data using `pd.read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/example.csv", sep=',')
```

```
print(df)
           name   age                                             address
0           john    25  koramangala banglore +ACMAQA- sales maneger +A...
1  harshuth rao     36  belandur banglore +ACMAQA-  maneger +ACUAJA- i...
2    vijay kumar    45  ulsoor banglore +ACMAQA- sales maneger +ACUAJA...
3          suhas    25  koramangala banglore +ACMAQA-analist +ACUAJA- ...
4         mithun    22  venkatapura banglore +ACMAQA- execitive +ACUAJ...
```

Next, use `str.split` to separate the data + `pd.concat` to join with the original:

```
v = df.pop('address').str.split('\s*\+.*?-\s*', expand=True)
v.columns = ['city', 'position', 'country']

df = pd.concat([df, v], 1)
```

```
print(df)
           name   age                   city       position country
0           john    25  koramangala banglore  sales maneger   india
1  harshuth rao     36     belandur banglore        maneger  india 
2    vijay kumar    45       ulsoor banglore  sales maneger   india
3          suhas    25  koramangala banglore        analist   india
4         mithun    22  venkatapura banglore      execitive   india
```

Finally, save to CSV:

```
df.to_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv")
```

Comment: its a csv file i dont know how to do it i am new to python and pandas how to import and remove address column and add 2 more columns and save the file plz help !!

Comment: @VipulRao Start with `df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/example.csv")` and then run this code. If that doesn't work, please open your CSV in sublime text or notepad and paste 5 rows in your question.

Comment: @COLDSPEED i tried the code its not working and i have edited my question

Comment: @coldspeed i dont understand can you help how to import and save. Can you give me entire code plz help me

Comment: @VipulRao See edit. I have literally served the answer to you on a platter. Please try to understand what is happening so you can figure these things out yourself next time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165447/discussion-between-vipul-rao-and-cs).

Comment: @coldspeed there is an error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @VipulRao Try upgrading to the latest version: `pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: @coldspeed not posible Downloading/unpacking pandas
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pandas
No distributions at all found for pandas
Storing complete log in /home/vipul/.pip/pip.log

Comment: @VipulRao What version of python are you using?

Comment: @coldspeed python 2.7.12

Comment: @VipulRao It should work ;x Try this with python3 instead, it has better support :)

Comment: @coldspeed bad time for me ;(